# profile an awk command?

Tags: awk, profiler

Probably a silly question, since awk commands are usually pretty compact and do just one or two operations...

Is there a way to profile and awk command?  ie.  if it uses gsub, split, sorting associative arrays,  is there an easy way to find out which part is bogging down the whole operation?

**EDIT:** Specifically I am looking for executing time for each subcommand, not how many times it was called.  is this possible?

Comment: Hmmm...adding total time to the profiling might be a reasonable size contribution to gawk.

Answer (score 2):

From the gawk man page:

> pgawk is the profiling version of gawk.  It is identical in  every  way
>          to  gawk,  except  that  programs run more slowly, and it automatically
>          produces an execution profile in the file awkprof.out when  done.   See
>          the --profile option, below.

so the answer would be yes if you are using the GNU implementation.

And to forstall your next question, the man page goes on to say

> dgawk  is  an awk debugger. Instead of running the program directly, it
>          loads the AWK source code and  then  prompts  for  debugging  commands.
>          Unlike gawk and pgawk, dgawk only processes AWK program source provided
>          with the -f option.  The debugger is documented in GAWK: Effective  AWK
>          Programming.

Answer (score 2):

There's an awk implementation with [a debugger similar to gdb, called dgawk](http://awk.info/?news/debugger).

You say you want execution time for each subcommand.
Here's how I do it, regardless of language:

Give it enough workload so it runs long enough, and time it with a watch (N seconds).
Then do it again, and while it's running, hit Ctrl-C.
Do backtrace to examine the stack, and copy that into a text editor.
Do that several times, like 10.

Any subcommand will appear on the stack for the fraction of time it spends.
So if `sort` is taking 50% of the time (N/2 seconds), it will appear on about 5 of those samples.

This tells you about big time-takers, not little ones. I assume you are looking for the big ones.

(Some people say this isn't accurate, which is baloney. Sure the amount of time isn't very accurate - it doesn't need to be. The accuracy you need is in location - pinpointing where the problem is, and that's what it does.)

ADDED: You can *almost* do this with [pgawk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Profiling.html). If you run your program in profiling mode, each time you hit Ctrl-C (or whatever) it prints the call stack to the output file. The only problem is, it prints the function names but not what lines they are called from, which you might actually need.

Answer (score 2):

Build a profiling version of gawk for gprof, or use the kernel-based oprofile. You can then see in a lot of detail how much time is spent in various internal functions in gawk in response to your script and its data. Functions like `gsub` and `split` map to functions inside `gawk`.

For instance `gsub` and other functions are handled by the `do_sub` function in this source file:

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/builtin.c

So you would look for how much time is spent in `do_sub`.

You want to compile and link gawk with the `-pg` GCC option.  Successful runs of the program will then dump a profiling file `gmon.out` from which `gprof` will produce a report.

I highly recommend oprofile also, but going into it little out of scope for this answer.

Comment: This is definitely the closest thing to an acceptable answer. Can you give a more thorough example of doing this in practice, or link to one? If I understand you correctly you are suggesting inferring profiling information about the code from information about the interpreter. While most often helpful it is not the most intuitive thing in the world.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the fine documentation about profiling gawk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Profiling.html).

Comment: Almost perfect.  Now how to tell how much time is spent on each command?

Comment: In that case, use the upvote button. Anyway: you can `print systime()`  anytime you want (seconds from EPOCH will be printed. And you can do some math with it too...

Comment: That feature looks more like coverage testing, telling you which lines have been hit how many times. That is useful, of course, but it's not profiling.

Comment: Note lonestar21's edit: *EDIT: Specifically I am looking for executing time for each subcommand, not how many times it was called.*